# The monoidal structure on the fundamental groupoids of spectrum

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, groupoids, spectra

I am trying to understand Anderson duality and Picard categories from appendix B of [Hopkins and Singer's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211216), and I somehow get stuck on Example B.7 (Page 87).

For a spectrum $E$, they consider each of the fundamental groupoids $\pi_{\leq 1}E_n$. Then they equipped a tensor product $$\otimes: E_n\times E_n\rightarrow E_n$$ with these groupoids, making them Picard categories.

I have some confusion about this procedure:

1. The precise meaning of $\pi_{\leq 1}E_n$. To my understanding, $\pi_{1}E_n$ is the category in which objects are points in $E_n$ and morphisms are homotopy classes of paths in $E_n$, so it is a groupoid. But $\pi_0E_n$ is the set of path-connected components of the space $E_n$, so it is not a groupoid in which objects are points in $E_n$. Then it seems to me that the tensor product they constructed only gives rise to a monoidal structure on the groupoids $\pi_{1}E_n$, but not the sets $\pi_{0}E_n$.
2. They identify the space $E_n$ with the space of maps of spectra $S^0\rightarrow \Sigma^n E$. I believe here they use $S^0$ for the sphere spectrum $S$, and the latter set is the collection of functions of degree $-r$ between $S$ and $E$. But I didn't figure out how this identification works.
3. Then they claimed that a choice of "loop multiplication" amounts to a choice of deformation of the diagonal $S^0\rightarrow S^0\times S^0$ to a map $S^0\rightarrow S^0\vee S^0$. I am quite confused about how can we get a map $\otimes: E_n\times E_n\rightarrow E_n$ from such a deformation.

Corrections and comments are welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\pi_{\leq 1}$ and your $\pi_1$ mean the same thing - $\pi_{\leq 1}$ is simply used to indicate that you take the groupoid and not just the fundamental group. If you think of groupoids as spaces, another reason to use $\pi_{\leq 1}$ is because you're seeing it as a $1$-truncation operation: you're chopping off everything $>1$, so you're left with $\leq 1$.

(note that $\pi_0$ *does* acquire the structure of an ordinary monoid/group because for any monoidal groupoid $\mathcal G$, $\pi_0\mathcal G$ has the structure of an ordinary monoid)

2. I'm unsure how to answer this because I'm unsure what you mean by "degree $-n$ maps" if not "maps $S^0\to \Sigma^n E$". $S^0$ is indeed the sphere spectrum here.
3. The construction goes : $E_n\times E_n = map(S^0,\Sigma^n E)\times map(S^0,\Sigma^n E)\simeq map(S^0\vee S^0, \Sigma^n E)$, then you precompose with your diagonal $S^0\to S^0\vee S^0$ to obtain something in $map(S^0, \Sigma^n E) = E_n$. All in all, this gives you $E_n\times E_n\to E_n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Sorry about my ignorance on the subject, but it seems I need some more elaboration. About question 1, do you mean that if we apply $\pi_{\leq 1}$ to some reasonable space $X$, we would get a space (surely also a groupoid) $\pi_{\leq 1}X$ with trival homotopy groups except $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$? About question 3, is $S^0\vee S^0$ a spectrum with $n$-th space $S^n\vee S^n$ (and obvious structure maps)? Also I failed to see why the isomorphism $map(S^0,\Sigma^n E)\times map(S^0,\Sigma^n E)\simeq map(S^0\vee S^0, \Sigma^n E)$ holds.

Comment: In question 2, I mean a sequence of maps compatible with suspension $f_k: S^k \rightarrow E_{n+k}$ by saying "a map of degree $-n$ between spectra $S^0$ and $E$".

Comment: Yes to your question about $\pi_{\leq 1}$ : if you believe that groupoids and spaces are the same thing, then yes this is exactly what you get :) For $S^0\vee S^0$, it depends on exactly what you mean by spectrum. Whatever it is, $S^0\vee S^0$ should be the *coproduct* in spectra of $S^0$ and itself, which explains the isomorphism $map(S^0,S^0,X) \simeq map(S^0,X)\times map(S^0,X)$ : it holds by definition of coproduct

Comment: Thank you @Maxime! Is this claim about $\pi_{\leq 1}$ an easy observation or a non-trival fact? I feel like I am missing something here...

Comment: I'm not sure which fact you mean - do you mean that such a thing exists ?

Comment: $\pi_{\leq 1}X$ has trivial homotopy groups except $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$.

Comment: That's essentially by definition :) so it depends on your definition

Comment: Sorry for my being slow on homotopy theory... To my understanding, for a space $X$, $\pi_{\leq 1}X$ is defined to be the category in which objects are points $X$, and morphisms are homotopy classes of paths in $X$. So I think space $X$ and $\pi_{\leq 1}X$ have the same underlying set, but I am not sure how the additional "morphisms" structure affects the topology (namely kills many homotopy groups) in $\pi_{\leq 1}X$.

Comment: So the point is that $\pi_{\leq 1}X$, defined as this category is not, strictly speaking, a space. It's a groupoid. There is then a correspondance between spaces and groupoids: any groupoid yields a space (its "geometric realization"), and this space is always $1$-truncated, that is, it has no homotopy group beyond $\pi_1$, its $\pi_0$ is that of the groupoid, and similarly for its $\pi_1$. If you apply this to $\pi_{\leq 1}X$, you obtain a space, say $X_{\leq 1}$, receiving a map $X\to X_{\leq 1}$ which is an isomorphism on $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$.

Comment: Because the homotopy theory of $1$-truncated spaces matches exactly that of groupoids, one typically abuses notation and writes both as $X_{\leq 1}$ or $\pi_{\leq 1} X$. They are also the same thing as the fundamental groupoid $\Pi_1(X)$ or $\pi_1 X$ in your notation

Answer (score 1):

Maxime Ramzi has already answered questions 1 and 3. I'll answer question 2.

This is really more of just a topological fact, namely we have the following isomorphisms (assuming the notation that $\Sigma$ is defined via shifting the indices of sequential spectra and $\Omega^\infty$ returns the zeroth space).
$$
E_n\simeq 
\mathbf{Top}(S^0,E_n) 
\simeq 
\mathbf{Top}(S^0,\Omega^\infty\Sigma^n E)
\simeq \mathbf{Sp}(\Sigma^\infty S^0, \Sigma^nE)
$$

**Edit in response to request for clarification below:**

For the last isomorphism, $\Sigma^\infty$ and $\Omega^\infty$ are adjoint functors, which is a fairly straightforward proof that I'll include below. As for a reference, any source that builds a category of spectra should have some sort of proof of this fact. I should note that by $\mathbf{Top}$ I mean the category of *pointed* topological spaces, specifically whichever category was used to build your notion of spectrum.

Now we want to prove that for $X\in\mathbf{Top}$, $E\in\mathbf{Sp}$,
$$\newcommand\Top{\mathbf{Top}}\newcommand\Sp{\mathbf{Sp}}
\Sp(\Sigma^\infty X, E)\simeq \Top(X,\Omega^\infty E).
$$
Now conveniently for us, $\Omega^\infty \Sigma^\infty X=X$, so $\Omega^\infty$ induces a map $\Sp(\Sigma^\infty X, E)\to \Top(X,\Omega^\infty E)$, and we just need to show that this map is a bijection. Again, $\Omega^\infty$ evaluates a sequential spectrum at its zeroth space, so it sends a map $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$ to $f_0$. (It doesn't matter whether your spectra are indexed by integers or natural numbers. I'm going to assume integers.)

Let's take a closer look at maps of spectra $f:\Sigma^\infty X\to E$.
$f$ has components $f_i : (\Sigma^\infty X)_i \to E_i$. For $i < 0$, $(\Sigma^\infty X)_i = *$, so $f_i$ must be the inclusion of the basepoint into $E_i$ for $i < 0$. For $i\ge 0$ we use the fact that maps of spectra commute with the structure maps of the spectra. Consider such a commutative square:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Sigma \Sigma^i X @>1>> \Sigma^{i+1} X\\
@V\Sigma f_iVV @VVf_{i+1}V \\
\Sigma E_i @>\sigma_i>> E_{i+1},
\end{CD}
$$
where $\sigma_i : \Sigma E_i\to E_{i+1}$ is the structure map in $E$.

This tells us that $f_{i+1} = \sigma_i\circ (\Sigma f_i)$ for all $i\ge 0$. In other words for $i>0$, $f_i$ is determined by $f_0$.

In fact, not only is $f_i$ determined by $f_0$ if we start with a morphism of spectra $f:\Sigma^\infty X \to E$, for any map $h:X\to E_0$ we can define a map $g : \Sigma^\infty X \to E$ by taking $g_0=h$, $g_i = *\to E_i$ for $i < 0$, and
inductively defining
$g_{i+1} = \sigma_i \circ (\Sigma g_i)$ for $i \ge 0$.

This gives us a map $\Top(X,\Omega^\infty E)\to \Sp(\Sigma^\infty X, E)$ that is inverse to the map induced by $\Omega^\infty$, proving the claim.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! The isomorphism $
\mathbf{Top}(S^0,\Omega^\infty\Sigma^n E)
\simeq \mathbf{Sp}(\Sigma^\infty S^0, \Sigma^nE)$ looks perfectly reasonable, could you tell me some reference where I can find the proof of it?

Comment: @timaeus Pretty much any source that defines spectra should prove that fact, but I've added a proof to my answer as well.