# Spectra, Picard categories and their k-invariants

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, mathematical-physics

I am trying to understand the following statement, which is taken from Appendix B, Proposition B.12 of [Hopkins and Singer's paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211216):

> The correspondence $$ E\mapsto \pi_{\leq 1}E_0 $$  is an equivalence
> between the 2-category of spectra E satisfying $\pi_iE=0, i\neq 0, 1$
> and the 2-category of Picard categories.

In a previous definition (Definition B.5), they defined the k-invariant of a Picard category $C$ as an abelian group homomorphism
$$\pi_0C\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow \pi_1C,$$ which is induced by a "twist" on the tensor product. Also, they had made $\pi_{\leq 1}E_n$ into a Picard category in Example B.7 (see my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4469542/the-monoidal-structure-on-the-fundamental-groupoids-of-spectrum)).

In the proof of the above proposition, it seems to me they were relating the following two concepts of k-invariants:

1. k-invariant for Postnikov tower of spectra
2. k-invariant for Picard category

More precisely, for a spectrum $E$ with only $\pi_0,\pi_1$ nontrivial, its k-invariant (from the Postnikov tower of $E$)
$$ H\pi_0E\rightarrow \Sigma^2H\pi_1E$$
determines its homotopy type. Then they claimed that

> The set of homotopy classes of maps $ H\pi_0E\rightarrow \Sigma^2H\pi_1E$ is naturally isomorphic to $$\mathrm{hom}(A\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2, B).$$

without pointing out what $A$ and $B$ are referring to. After that, they concluded the proof by relating the two concepts of k-invariant:

> One can associate to a Picard category with k-invariant $\epsilon$, the spectrum E with the same k-invariant.

I am quite confused by their proof. Especially the part involving $A$ and $B$, also how they transfer the k-invariant of Postnikov tower to the k-invariant of Picard category.

Thank you in advance for any comments, answers, and corrections!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are just $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$; they’re citing a nontrivial but old theorem of stable homotopy theory in moving to maps out of $A\otimes \mathbb Z/2.$

I’d suggest reading an actual proof of this result, which I believe wasn’t done until Johnson and Osorno here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.2686.pdf

Comment: Thank you Kevin for this most informative answer! I am still trying to figure out how this old theorem $[H\pi_0, \Sigma^2H\pi_1] \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_0/2\pi_0, \pi_1)$ works. In the paper you mentioned, the authors cited "(2.7)" from a paper by Eilenberg and MacLane, which I found to be some commutative rule for face and degeneracy maps. I find it hard to see how this rule leads to the isomorphism. Could you please give me some further clues about it?

Comment: @timaeus Oh, no! I'm not immediately sure of a better reference for that bit.

Comment: @timaeus I think the reference "(2.7)" in Johnson-Osorno should instead be (27.1) in the section "Higher cohomology groups" in the Eilenberg-MacLane paper.

Comment: @timaeus Here are some remarks from a friend I convinced to look into this a bit more. As JHF says, the intended reference in the paper you cited is (27.1). This is at the very end of a formidable paper and used many results obtained along the way. 

The proof is by computing $H^5(K(A, 3); B),$ which is in the stable range; this is done by the universal coefficient theorem and the computation of integral homology groups in Section 23, in particular (23.2) and Theorem 23.1. (1/4)

Comment: The relevant part of (23.2) --- that $H_4(K(3, \Pi); \mathbb Z) = 0$ --- is Theorem 20.5, which is straightforward when $\Pi$ is cyclic (compute for Moore spaces), but requires understanding "cross effects" to handle the necessary direct limit arguments. (2/4)

Comment: Theorem 23.1 --- the computation $H_5(K(\Pi, 3); \mathbb Z)$ --- requires understanding the explicit cell structure of these complexes, introduced by EM in these papers, and a previous computation of $H_4(K(\Pi, 2); \mathbb Z).$ This computation, Theorem 21.1, is in terms of a "Gamma" functor introduced earlier in the paper. They argue by a direct limit arguments it suffices to prove the claim for $\Pi$ cyclic, where they do it by extremely explicit computation using techniques described in Sections 14 and 15. (3/4)

Comment: It is probably going to be extremely difficult to read this in any way other than from the start. Another more recent reference that proves the same (more?) results is https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5676 which seems to be self contained at a glance. (4/4)

Comment: Thank you @Kevin (and also your friend) so much for these great remarks!